# What version gems should I be using?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, guard, spork

I have been following the tutorial on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages and I have ruby 2.0.0 with Rails 4.0.2.  I have Guard installed and it is configured to use spork.  Everythign is working - sorta.

I am experiencing a bug noted here https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/495

I have tried changing the version requirements so I use the latest version of the gems in my development group but when changing something that triggers guard to run the specs it runs them 3 times.

Here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  #gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'rspec-rails'#, '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec'#, '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails'#, '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork'#, '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess'#, '0.4.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'libnotify'#, '0.8.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
```

Here is my GuardFile

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme
require 'active_support/inflector'
interactor :simple
guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end

guard :rspec, all_after_pass: false, cli: '--drb' do

  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { 'spec' }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { 'spec' }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { 'spec/routing' }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { 'spec/controllers' }
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) { |m| (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")}
  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml|slim)$})     { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

Here is my spec helper:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  rubymine_home = '/home/matt/Desktop/RubyMine-6.0.3/'
  if rubymine_home
    $:.unshift(File.expand_path('rb/testing/patch/common', rubymine_home))
    $:.unshift(File.expand_path('rb/testing/patch/bdd', rubymine_home))
  end

... Defaults Here ...

end
Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

Here is the results of bundle show

```
Gems included by the bundle:
    * actionmailer (4.0.2)
    * actionpack (4.0.2)
    * activemodel (4.0.2)
    * activerecord (4.0.2)
    * activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    * activesupport (4.0.2)
    * arel (4.0.2)
    * atomic (1.1.14)
    * builder (3.1.4)
    * bundler (1.5.3)
    * capybara (2.1.0)
    * celluloid (0.15.2)
    * celluloid-io (0.15.0)
    * childprocess (0.4.2)
    * coderay (1.1.0)
    * coffee-rails (4.0.1)
    * coffee-script (2.2.0)
    * coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    * diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    * erubis (2.7.0)
    * execjs (2.0.2)
    * ffi (1.9.3)
    * formatador (0.2.4)
    * guard (2.4.0)
    * guard-rspec (2.5.0)
    * guard-spork (1.5.0)
    * hike (1.2.3)
    * i18n (0.6.9)
    * jbuilder (1.0.2)
    * jquery-rails (3.0.4)
    * json (1.8.1)
    * libnotify (0.8.0)
    * listen (2.5.0)
    * lumberjack (1.0.4)
    * mail (2.5.4)
    * method_source (0.8.2)
    * mime-types (1.25.1)
    * mini_portile (0.5.2)
    * minitest (4.7.5)
    * multi_json (1.8.4)
    * mysql2 (0.3.15)
    * nio4r (1.0.0)
    * nokogiri (1.6.1)
    * polyglot (0.3.3)
    * pry (0.9.12.6)
    * rack (1.5.2)
    * rack-test (0.6.2)
    * rails (4.0.2)
    * railties (4.0.2)
    * rake (10.1.1)
    * rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
    * rb-inotify (0.9.3)
    * rdoc (3.12.2)
    * rspec (2.13.0)
    * rspec-core (2.13.1)
    * rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
    * rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    * rspec-rails (2.13.1)
    * rubyzip (0.9.9)
    * sass (3.2.14)
    * sass-rails (4.0.1)
    * sdoc (0.3.20)
    * selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
    * slop (3.4.7)
    * spork (1.0.0rc4)
    * spork-rails (4.0.0)
    * sprockets (2.10.1)
    * sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
    * thor (0.18.1)
    * thread_safe (0.1.3)
    * tilt (1.4.1)
    * timers (1.1.0)
    * treetop (1.4.15)
    * turbolinks (1.1.1)
    * tzinfo (0.3.38)
    * uglifier (2.1.1)
    * websocket (1.0.7)
    * xpath (2.0.0)
```

I have been programming in ruby on rails for only 4 days (and 2 of those were trying to get it working).  Why does gem compatibility have to be so complicated!?  What should I be using to fix the guard problem I am having?

Comment: To be honest, if you're that new to rails, I wouldn't worry about Guard and Spork just yet and concentrate on Rails. Don't overcomplicate things where you don't need to. In any case, most people are dropping Guard/Spork for Zeus now anyway. :)

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the input.  I am just trying to do what tutorials tell me to :-P.  I am used to PHP and can learn any language pretty quickly.  I LOVE the way rails is setup.  I especially like the rspec unit testing.  I think I just figured out the answer too :-/.

Answer (score 1):

I had been working on this for almost an hour before posting the question but then it dawned on me that guard-rspec is what needs to be updated.  I don't know how to tell ruby to use the latest stable version.  If someone could clarify that in a comment I would appreciate it.

Solution was to change the gem file :
gem 'guard-rspec', '4.2.6'

Then do bundle update

And kill and run guard again (or for some bundle exec guard)

Comment: If you don't specify numbers, bundler will grab the latest available version when you run `bundle update`. Also, check out http://gemnasium.com for monitoring whether your gems are getting out of date. It's free for open repositories.

Comment: In addition, when you don't specify any version numbers, Bundler might sometimes use an older version of a gem if that also resolves. Be sure to check your Gemfile.lock after each bundle update.

Comment: @iain I am experiencing this.  How do I correct bundle and force it to get the newest gem?  (besides specifying the exact version in my gemfile)

Comment: @Bil1 you need to give Bundler a version number to work with. There is no way around it. It doesn't need to be exact. Something like `> 2.0` for example will tell bundler to ignore the really old versions. After you've excluded the stupid version combinations Bundler will usually be smart enough.